# Java generic fields

Tags: java, generics

I have a PlayerCharacter class.
PlayerCharacter can be extended (for example, VampirePlayerCharacter vs WerewolfPlayerCharacter)

I have a Trait class.  Trait can be extended (for example, Generation or Gnosis).

`PlayerCharacter` has a method, `#withTrait(Trait)`, which adds the Trait to a collection.
`PlayerCharacter` has a method, `#applyAllTraits()` which loops through the collection and applies each of them to the character.

A `VampirePlayerCharacter` should be able to be given any `Trait` that could apply to a `PlayerCharacter`, as well as any `Trait` that could only apply to a `VampirePlayerCharacter`.

So I added a generic type, making `Trait<PC extends PlayerCharacter>`

Thus, there can be `BasicTrait<PlayerCharacter>` and `Generation<VampirePlayerCharacter>`

My conundrum:

- If PlayerCharacter's collection of traits is `Collection<Trait<PlayerCharacter>>`, then `VampirePlayerCharacter` can't add a `Trait<VampirePlayerCharacter>` to the collection.
- If `PlayerCharacter`'s collection of traits is `Collection<Trait<? extends PlayerCharacter>>`, then `VampirePlayerCharacter` can add a `Trait<VampirePlayerCharacter>` to the collection.  However, `PlayerCharacter` can no longer loop through the traits, because their type is indeterminate (it could be `Trait<PlayerCharacter>` or a `Trait<VampirePlayerCharacter>` or a `Trait<WerewolfPlayerCharacter>` or...)
- If `PlayerCharacter`'s collection of traits is `Collection<Trait<? super PlayerCharacter>>`, then `VampirePlayerCharacter` can't add a `Trait<VampirePlayerCharacter>`, because `VampirePlayerCharacter` isn't a supertype of `PlayerCharacter`

I'm about a hair's-breadth from saying that more specialized traits just have to use a cast in their apply method and if you set things up inappropriately, they'll explode- but I'm *certain* that this is not a novel problem, and I just can't wrap my head around the solution.

```
class PlayerCharacter {
  private int str;
  List<Trait<?>> traits = new ArrayList<>();

  PlayerCharacter withStrength(int str) {
    this.str = str;
    return this;
  }
  PlayerCharacter withTrait(Trait trait) {
    this.traits.add(trait);
    return this;
  }

  void applyTraits() {
    traits.forEach((Trait<?> t) -> t.apply(this));
  }
}

class VampirePlayerCharacter extends PlayerCharacter {
  private int fangLength;
  VampirePlayerCharacter  withFangLength(int fangLength) {
    this.fangLength = fangLength;
    return this;
  }
}

abstract class Trait<PC extends PlayerChracter> {
  void apply(PC pc);
}

class StrengthTrait extends Trait<PlayerCharacter> {
  private int str;
  StrengthTrait(int str) {
    this.str = str;
  }

  void apply(PlayerCharacter pc) {
    pc.withStrength(str);
  }
}

class FangLengthTrait extends Trait<VampirePlayerCharacter> {
  private int fangLength;
  FangLengthTrait(int fangLength) {
    this.fangLength = fangLength;
  }

  void apply(VampirePlayerCharacter pc) {
    pc.withFangLength(fangLength);
  }
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: I don't think inheritance is a good idea for trying to manage these objects.  Look up Strategy Pattern and Decorator Pattern, perhaps one of those might be useful for you.

Comment: You could try an interface

Comment: sorry but your design is flawed - `Trait`of Type `PlayerCharacter` doesnt make much sense, it should be more like a `Field` in `PlayerCharacter`, also : your nomenclature is confusing, i'd recommend changing `PlayerCharacter` to `Character<Player>` and possibly `Character<NonPlayer>` or something similar, that'll clear things up a bit. Also : `Trait`s dont need to be "applied" to a `Character`, they should only be added, changed or removed. It really helps later on if you clear your design up and make everything logical, consistent and easy to read, even if you're the one and only developer.

Comment: Neither Strategy nor Decorator really seem appropriate- the behavior isn't changing, just the types.

Comment: specializt - I don't understand how shuffling the names around would resolve the issue.

And the traits are applied distinctly from being added for domain reasons (namely, so a third party can look at proposed changes and approve them either singularly or en masse.

Comment: MeetTitan - What interface would you suggest extracting?  Having an ITrait seems like the obvious choice, but then implementors of ITrait that only want to act on specific children of PlayerCharacter would still have to cast.

Comment: nomenclature is _THE_ most important thing in software development - bad software has confusing names and derails your train of thought and good software doesnt. The first stage is planning, conceptualizing a COMPLETELY clear design - if that is done you will have MUCH less problems with many things, solutions to problems will simply leap to the eye - which isnt the case if you yourself need to re-iterate everything and remind yourself of your inital goals everytime you asess a new / old problem

Comment: specializt, I don't disagree on the value of clean and clear names.  However, I don't understand how changing the names in this case will support the behavior that I'm aiming for.  

Since you feel you understand my domain well enough to suggest alternate naming conventions, I trust that you also understand the behavior I'm looking for, and can perhaps explain how the names you're suggesting support that behavior.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well the problem is that you need to retain your inheritance as generic type information.

Basically you would have to do something like:

```
class PlayerCharacter<P extends PlayerCharacter<P>> {
    List<Trait<? super P>> myTraits;
}

class VampirePlayer extends PlayerCharacter<VampirePlayer> {...}

abstract class Trait<P extends PlayerCharacter<P>> {
    abstract void apply(P player);
}

class FangLengthTrait extends Trait<VampirePlayer> {...}
```

It begins to get very clunky, though. You can somewhat improve the situation by approaching from composition:

```
class Attributes {}

class Base extends Attributes {
    int strength;
}

class Vampire extends Base {
    int fangLength;
}

class Player<A extends Attributes> {
    final A attributes;
    final List<Trait<? super A>> traits = new ArrayList<>();

    Player(A attributes) {
        this.attributes = attributes;
    }

    void applyTraits() {
        for(Trait<? super A> t : traits)
            t.apply(this);
    }
}

interface Trait<A extends Attributes> {
    void apply(Player<? extends A> player);
}

class StrengthTrait implements Trait<Base> {
    @Override
    public void apply(Player<? extends Base> player) {
        player.attributes.strength = 1000;
    }
}

class FangLengthTrait implements Trait<Vampire> {
    @Override
    public void apply(Player<? extends Vampire> player) {
        player.attributes.fangLength = 100;
    }
}

final class Factory {
    private Factory() {}

    public static Player<Base> newPlayer() {
        return new Player<Base>(new Base());
    }

    public static Player<Vampire> newVampire() {
        return new Player<Vampire>(new Vampire());
    }
}
```

I still find it clunky, personally. If you are mainly just using these `Trait`s to construct objects you might think about using a builder or factory so you don't need to use generics.

Comment: This has mostly convinced me that generics aren't the proper solution for this problem.  :)

(I also realized that I could just rely on method overloading, with children of Trait having more precise apply methods.  It's a little tricky, but seems to be working)